# How to ignore last row in filter suggestion in MS Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

Here Two columns filter contain its data, Data1 column filter contain 2,2,3,4 and 11. but 11 is a sum of that column using formula. How can i ignore it from filter suggestion?

Comment: It is not intended to manually add a total row. Go to Table Tools, Design, Table Style Options and check Total Row then use the subtotal formula from C7 in B7 and modify it for the correct column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have basically two options:

1. Format each column as one table and make a total row:
   [image: Total Row]

2.Use the Subtotal Function. For example:

```
=SUBTOTAL(9;I5:I8)
```

Though I might have missed some other options.

Comment: it can be one table with two or more columns but the subtotal formula may have to be manually added to some columns.

Comment: Thnk you : ) @prextor

Answer (score 1):

I agree with prextor, table formatting is the way to go.

But if you aren't formatting as a table a quick fix could just be to add a row before the totals row you have, then the filter will ignore the totals row.

Also, as prextor suggested, instead of using a SUM() on the totals row, you should use `SUBTOTAL(9,B3:B6)` and `SUBTOTAL(9,C3:C6)`

[Screenshot (1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFQlb.png)

[Screenshot (2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AQBA.png)

Comment: Thank you ! I used this method. set there one empty row as in screenshot now its working nicely :)

Comment: That's great to hear :)